# How to clear WinInet cache created by IIS?

Tags: http, caching, httpwebrequest, wininet

Using the [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)/WebRequest API in C# to build a REST API client. I've changed the underlying [RequestCachePolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cache.requestcachepolicy.aspx) to allow it to cache responses that have the appropriate HTTP cache control headers. This is working great.

However, I often want to clear the cache during testing. Everything I've read says that

1. The underlying implementation is the [WinInet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) cache.
2. You can clear it via Internet Explorer.
3. On Win7 the cache is stored in C:\Users\namehere\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files

When my code is **deployed to IIS** in a middle-tier scenario, and the HTTP client is executing from there, I've found that

1. The underlying implementation is still the WinInet cache.
2. Internet Explorer **doesn't** clear it.
3. It's stored in C:\Windows\Temp\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\

*I was able to use System.Net tracing to monitor the client side cache behavior.*

**My question is how to clear this Content.IE5 cache in a non-programmatic way.** Certainly I can go in and delete the files by hand, but its a hassle with all the alphanumeric folders under Content.IE5, etc.

Comment: I would imagine it is because when deployed in IIS it is running under a *different* (system?) account. IE settings/cache are generally per account; so it may be that the "clear" is just being done in the wrong context.

Comment: @pst I reached the same conclusion. Haven't figured out yet how to clear it as the app pool user..

Comment: As the app pool user, run the ClearMyTracks command in inetcpl.cpl using rundll32